# Не отображается cardView в recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Вопрос довольно простой, но решить его не получается. Во фрагменте recyclerView с карточками. Фрагмент и recyclerView отображаются, карточки нет. Карточка довольно крупная, под тулбаром прятаться не может.

```
public class PoemFragment extends Fragment {
        private List<ModelPoem> list;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootViewPoem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poem, container, false);

            list = new ArrayList<>();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootViewPoem.findViewById(R.id.rvPoem); //       
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            adapter = new MyAdapter(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return rootViewPoem;

        } }



  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter. MyViewHolder> {
    private List<ModelPoem> list;

    public MyAdapter(List<ModelPoem> list) {

        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter. MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyAdapter. MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_poem, parent, false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter. MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelPoem modelPoem = list.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(modelPoem.getTitle());
        holder.poem.setText(modelPoem.getPoem());
        holder.years.setText(modelPoem.getYears());
        holder.subject.setText(modelPoem.getSubject());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView poem;
        CardView cv;
        TextView subject;
        TextView years;
        ImageView subject_image;
        ImageView years_image;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            poem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            years = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_years);
            subject_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_subject);
            years_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_years);
```

разметка (текстовые данные заполнены лишь для проверки)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="30dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:text="title"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_poem"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="test....................
.........................................................."/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/separator" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:divider="@drawable/separator"
                android:dividerPadding="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:showDividers="middle">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingEnd="30dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_subject"
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="18dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pound" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_subject"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:text="subject"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="30dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_years"
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="18dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar_range" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_years"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:text="years"/>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

разметка фрагмента

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.PoemFragment">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPoem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="88dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Может вы её просто не замечаете? Попробуйте цвет фона у неё поменять. Ну или деталей добавьте в вопрос - пока не ясно где эта карточка у вас в разметке должна быть и самой разметки также просто не видно в вопросе.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавила разметку.  Цвета там разные и есть иконки

Comment: Кажется очень странным `android:layout_height="match_parent"` во многих вьюхах. Особенно в первом потоке самой карточки. Попробуйте `wrap_content` проставить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Поменяла и обновила разметку в вопросе. Не помогло.

Comment: Ну... Может вы просто данные не добавили для отображения? В коде у вас просто пустой список... Если добавили - покажите как и покажите скриншот.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я создавала вопрос на en_SO 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988416/room-migrate-the-full-database-recyclerview  т.к именно при заполнении данными приложении запускалось с пустым фрагментом. Меня направили искать проблему в другом месте. В итоге фрагмент отображается, ресайклер отображается(если ему поменять background), а карточки (пускай без данных, но ведь там есть иконки)  одной единственной нет. Может быть я не там проблему ищу... скриншот приложила

Comment: Если вы показали весь код, то данных в адаптере у вас нет и потому и не отображается ничего. Вы в адаптер передаёте `list = new ArrayList<>()` - т.е. пустой список. Или вы его потом где-то в другом месте наполняете, но не вызываете метод адаптера для его перерисовки. Сама по себе карточка не появится, если никаких данных для адаптера нет.

Comment: Вы были правы. Заполнила лист и карточки появились. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данных в адаптере у вас нет и потому и не отображается ничего. Вы в адаптер передаёте `list = new ArrayList<>()` - т.е. пустой список. Или вы его потом где-то в другом месте наполняете, но не вызываете метод адаптера для его перерисовки (`notifyDataSetChanged()`). Сама по себе карточка не появится, если никаких данных для адаптера нет.